# Where is the error in my code VBA checking date

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

I have a code that when the user clicks on the button the system compares between the current date and the written date, then fills the cell with the appropriate color.

The problem is that if before 2 days I wrote 10-16-2017 it will fill the background in red. If I check today it must turn the color to yellow. **the problem is that once the cell is colored it never changes color.**

**Example:**

Date 10-16-2017 was written 3 ago so the initial color will be red.

Today is 10-16-2017 so when I press the button it must change to yellow.

**Here's my code:**

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = Range("C5000").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1 'Range upto 5000, chnge this as per your requirment'
        If IsEmpty(Cells(i, 3)) Then
            Exit Sub
        ElseIf (VBA.CDate(Cells(i, 3)) - VBA.Date()) < 0 Then
            Cells(i, 3).Interior.Color = vbGreen

        ElseIf (VBA.CDate(Cells(i, 3)) - VBA.Date()) = 0 Then
            Cells(i, 3).Interior.Color = vbYellow

        ElseIf (VBA.CDate(Cells(i, 3)) - VBA.Date()) >= 1 And (VBA.CDate(Cells(i, 3)) - VBA.Date()) <= 4 Then
            Cells(i, 3).Interior.Color = vbRed

        ElseIf (VBA.CDate(Cells(i, 3)) - VBA.Date()) >= 5 And (VBA.CDate(Cells(i, 3)) - VBA.Date()) <= 10 Then
            Cells(i, 3).Interior.Color = vbCyan

        Else
            Cells(i, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: This works perfectly on my end; is it possible that due to a lack of worksheet reference, it's pointing to the wrong spot on yours? I would `Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Whatever_Your_Sheet_Name_Is")` and then specify all your ranges/cells as `ws.Range(...)` and `ws.Cell(...)` and see if that helps.

Comment: guys the problem is that if i write now 10-14-2017 and click the button it will color Green... BUT IF i had written 10-14-2107  in  10-14-2017  as the current it will colored yellow and will never change  that is my problem

Comment: Yes, it is `<0` since it was 2 days ago.

Comment: @Dany7elo Could you edit your question to make the conditions clear, it seems confusing as it is.

Comment: @Dany7elo Did my solution work ? It'd be good to accept my answer by hitting the button below the up/down vote!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If IsEmpty(Cells(i, 3)) Then   Exit Sub   is your problem.
If there is a blank cell in the range, if one is found, your code will stop.

Edit this line. your code will work well.

```
    If IsEmpty(Cells(i, 3)) Then
         Cells(i, 3).Interior.Color = xlNone
```